# How to have custom dialog on preference activity?

Tags: android

I have a preference page where there is a check box preference for enable login password. When the user check it, it should have a dialog pop out and inside there will be **2 edit text** fields for password.

I have done some readings and it seems like using a custom dialog will be the right choice. But the problem is that there is no onCreateDialog() method for the preference activity to override, how do I solve this problem?
Some example codes will be nice. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need that method.. direcly create dialog and say **dialog.show()**

Comment: I need 2 edit text view, the dialog setview() only take 1 view isn't it?

Comment: well, you could create a LinearLayout instead, then add 2 text views inside, and call setView() with your LinearLayout as argument.

Comment: Then create an Activity with **Theme.Dialog**

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom subclass of `DialogPreference` that handles your dialog and persists your preference value, and use that in your preference XML resource.